# Need help to find right language detection configuration

Tags: i18n-l10n

We are developing a site with 10s of thousands of nodes and 12 interface and content languages. Having spent hours trying different configurations for language detection, I cannot find one that meets our requirements. Advice would be greatly appreciated. Here is our requirement:

**A. When someone comes to the website for the first time**
If our site has the language of their browser default, then the interface language and initial content should show in their browser language. Otherwise it defaults to English.

**B. After they have first arrived**
If the interface language (and content) a visitor sees is not the one they want, they will probably try to change to their language (if it exists) via the language selector.
Once they have their desired interface language set, most users are unlikely to change it to another.
So as they move around the site they see content in their chosen language, if it exists, otherwise the content appears in English (or another language, if no English version of the content).
The interface language should never change unless the user selects a different one in the language selector dropdown.

**C. Further questions**
Is it best practice in Drupal that there should always be a language code in the url, even if it is the default language (in our case English)?
If so, can we avoid having multilingual URL aliases?
Since if someone goes to a url without a language identifier they get a Page Not Found error, can one set up a redirect so that if there is no language code in the url it will default to /en?

**Our configuration that does not work**
To achieve our requirement I assumed that the config in this screenshot would achieve it. But it does not. The /en (or other language code) in the url does not call the right content, and the ?language=fr parameter does not force the right interface. What am I doing wrong?

[image]